# Woocommerce show products in their respective categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WordPress and Woocommerce plugin in my store. In normal mode Woocommerce displays products without grouping by categories. 
What I want is that,display products in their respective categories.
For example on shop page, At first show one category's title and then show its products under it, then next category and its products...
something like [this picture](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8183033000/woocommerce_category.png)

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried/what you have so far/an example of what you're working with so that we can help

Comment: You are the cancer that is killing SO.

Comment: @Mathemats And some bad drugs may be causes to grow that cancer...I explained what I know about it and what I want, so now, those who know about WordPress and Woocommerce can help me,not everybody...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I used shotcodes and [Woocommerce shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-shortcodes) plugin, as Anil.N said in his answer.

By installing that plugin, an option is added to the Text editor, which makes  easier to use of Shortcodes.
I used a shortcode like this:

```
[product_category category="Games" per_page="6" columns="3" orderby="date" order="DESC"]
```

And used it in a new page, then in Options>Reading I used that page for home page.(We can use a `<h2> or <h1>` tag for title of each category before each Shortcode)

Answer (score 0):

for displaying the products with respective category you can use this shortcode
[product_categories  parent="0"], you can create a new page and put this shortcode and you will see the category listing.